# PHP & MySQL: Count and order most popular values in an array and then print

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am wanting to order my array by how many times a value comes up in that array and also then print only the highest 6 results.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
        $delimiter = " ";
        $tags = array();

        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT tags FROM share WHERE site_id = $id");

        while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
            $tags_new = explode($delimiter, $result['tags']);
            $tags = array_merge($tags , $tags_new);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hum... You can do that:

```
    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $tags_new = explode($delimiter, $result['tags']);
        foreach($tags_new as $tag){
            $tags[$tag]++;
        }
    }
```

After, you need to sort by value, using function `sort` or `rsort` (desc).

```
    rsort($tags);
```

Last, you need slice and get only 6 first:

```
    $high_tags = array_slice($tags, 0, 6, true);
```

**Edit**: showing key and value:

```
    foreach($high_tags as $key => $value){
        echo "{$key}: {$value}";
    }
```

Or just do:

```
    $high_keys = array_keys($high_tags);

    var_dump($high_keys);
```

Bye :)

Comment: PS: I agree with Jason answer. Is better that mine for big results (and optimizations too).

Comment: thanks, but after review I don't think the OP stored `tags` in a relational way. So your answer may be what they *have to* use.

Comment: thanks for the help so far. At the moment the code you provided above is printing the number of times the value comes up and not the value itself.

Comment: You need to get the key. I edited my code for you understand. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in MySQL with the following query:

```
SELECT tags, COUNT(tags) AS tag_count
FROM share WHERE site_id = $id
GROUP BY tags
ORDER BY tag_count DESC
LIMIT 6;
```

This will select the top 6 tags with the highest count. You can then loop over them similar to the PHP code you already have.

Comment: What changes would I have to make to make inorder for this to work?

Comment: You would need to store `tags` in a more relational manner. So instead of storing multiple tags in one record, store each tag in multiple records. Then you would be able to use the query above and others to determine statistical information.